# "com.example.firstpage.ContactsDB.createGroup(ContactsDB.java:47)" and "com.example.firstpage.CreateGroup$1.onClick(CreateGroup.java:38)"

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception

I was trying to create a table in database by reading contents from an EditText(the EditText content is table name).

```
   imgbtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String gpname = ed1.getText().toString();  //  ed1 is object of EditText
            db.createGroup(gpname);                    //  db is object of database class and this is CreateGroup.java:38
            tv2.setText(gpname);
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+gpname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            vf.setDisplayedChild(1);
        }
    });
```

This is the code in database class to create table :

```
public void createGroup(String gpname) {
    String sql = "insert into groups(groupname) values('" + gpname + "'')";
    db1.execSQL(sql);                                         //  This is ContactsDB.java:47

    String query = "create table '" + gpname
            + "' (groupname text, name text primary key, number text)";
    db1.execSQL(query);
}
```

The exception details are :

```
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at com.example.firstpage.ContactsDB.createGroup(ContactsDB.java:47)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at com.example.firstpage.CreateGroup$1.onClick(CreateGroup.java:38)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-08 10:17:27.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why this errors occured ?

Comment: Can u show us the **code at line 47 of ContactsDB.java class.???**

Comment: @NadeemIqbal I had already commented it in the code..

Comment: @Code-Apprentice How db1 is null ?

Comment: Because you haven't initialized it. I cannot say more than that because you didn't show the full class, which probably includes a member variable declaration named `db1`.

Comment: See [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DbHelper) for an example of how to initialize your database object. In particular, you need to look at the constructor in the example code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You said it right. But when I initialized, I got some more exceptions.

Comment: you got error at db1.execSQL(sql); means it's error in either db1 object or sql string

Comment: @ManuJacob Please post a new question with the code that initializes your `db1` variable and post the errors that you get (as well as the code that causes the errors.

Comment: @PRAKASHUBHADIYA If `sql` was `null`, then the NPE would be thrown from somewhere inside the `execSQL()` call. Since the NPE is thrown at the line in the OP's code, `db1` must be `null`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for your help. Now all errors are corrected.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i know manu not initialize db1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `db1` Variable is null, please initialize it before using `db1` variable...

```
public void createGroup(String gpname) {
    String myPath = AppSettings.DB_Path + AppSettings.DATABASE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    // Now you can use `db1`...
    String sql = "insert into groups(groupname) values('" + gpname + "'')";
    db1.execSQL(sql);                                         //  This is ContactsDB.java:47

    String query = "create table '" + gpname
            + "' (groupname text, name text primary key, number text)";
    db1.execSQL(query); 
}
```

Comment: Why are you playing with `accept` and `unacceptence` of answer